# Is it possible to set limit for users quota in gogs?

Tags: git, gogs

I was check in admin section, also looked in config files but there is not parameter to manage limit for users quota.

Is it possible in **[gogs](https://github.com/gogits/gogs)**?

Answer (score 0):

The closest was [issue 1575](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/1575) which was [implemented in v0.8.0](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/commit/2a0bb1fa906a4d135ed88de4f705c3ab7214e60c).

It only limits the user in the number of repos created, not in their size though.

There is also [issue 1294 "Ability to set max repository size"](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/1294), still open. As is [issue 1158 "Ability to view repository size"](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/1158)

Comment: So as I see it is not possible t osolve this problem. I think to use gogs as git server for colaboration and if not gogs so what is possible other variant?

Comment: @Kaxa You still can use gogs, but you need to have a separate process monitoring the size of the repos created per users.

Comment: @Kaxa Also, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (for this or your previous questions)

Comment: Setting quota for users in repository directory gogs-repositories will solve this problem?